# ESP32 Host Receiving Post requests

Tags: python-requests, http-post, esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm attempting to use an ESP32 board as an access point, and then communicate between my laptop and the board to give it the correct credentials for a wifi network to join. I'm using python requests library to send a post request to the ESP32, which is using the SPAsyncWebServer and WiFi libraries. Get requests are working fine between the two, but post requests cause a panic and reboot of the board. Would anyone be able to help? I'm currently trying to post string data, I've seen that JSON files could be an alternative, but don't know much about them or how they could be implemented in this context, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Hi JoshFuller, welcome to SO. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, we can't do anything to help you without your relevant code and console output. Please update your post so it becomes a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check your monitor output. A lot of messages are printed up to the point of the panic/reboot and it will usually show where it went in the code lading up to the panic. If you're having trouble interpreting it, then showing that section of it in your question would be a good start in providing adequate detail in your question.